# Decision Feedback Equalizer, what is the use of it if data are already detected?

Tags: digital-communications

Since the decision feedback equalizer relies on correctly estimating the symbols in a detector before the feedback  , what is the use of it if the symbols have already been correctly detected?

Answer (score 1):

The equalizer helps to decode data *later on*, which then helps the equalizer do a better job, etc., ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

A decision feedback equalizer uses the detected value of symbol *n-1* (and possibly *n-2*, etc.) when decoding symbol *n*.

Symbol *n* is not already decoded when you're decoding symbol *n*, but it's also not used for decoding symbol *n*. Symbol *n-1* is already decoded when you're decoding symbol *n*.